# open addressing collision resolution

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, collision-detection

I faced a difficulty while implementing open addressing hash table in the c programming language:

```
#ifndef COMDS_OPENADDR_HASH_TABLE
#define COMDS_OPENADDR_HASH_TABLE

#define COMDS_KEY_EXIST 1
#define COMDS_REALLOC_FAIL  2

struct kv_pairs {
    void *key;
    void *value;
};

typedef struct openaddr_hash_table {
    size_t buckets;
    size_t used;
    size_t (*hash)(void *data);
    struct kv_pairs *table; 
    int (*key_equal)(void *fkey, void *skey);
    int (*value_equal)(void *fvalue, void *svalue);
}OpenAddrHashTable;
#endif
```

So here I use a array of struct kv_pairs, to hold my keys and value, the problem is that i must have 3 special values: **DELETED**, **USED**, **FREE** to indicate that the location is deleted/used/free, I don't know how to encode these value?

I tried to set struct kv_pairs able and set **FREE** 0x0 **DELETED** 0x1 and **USED** 0x2, and doing the comparison like that

```
table[i] == FREE || table[i] == (struct kv*)DELETED
```

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have tried? What problems do you have (besides comparing unrelated pointers which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))? Have you tried adding a flag to either structure?

Comment: You can't determine a value which will definitely be a non-valid address value on any given platform. So don't go defining those 3 values. Instead, allocate 3 global or static variables, and use their addresses. In addition, you probably want to make the comparison with `table[i].value` (though it's a little hard to understand from the question).

Comment: i will try to check if the table[i] is free or used before checking the value

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit confusing and I'm supposing that you're not trying to access already freed memory (which your question makes me think you are).
Adding an enum tag to struct kv_pair would be an easy solution

```
struct kv_pair {
    enum { KV_PAIR_FREE, KV_PAIR_DELETED, KV_PAIR_USED } tag;
    void *key;
    void *value;
};
```

Or you could add a separate array (possibly allocated together) of tags to struct openaddr_hash_table

```
enum tag { KV_PAIR_FREE, KV_PAIR_DELETED, KV_PAIR_USED};
struct openaddr_hash_table {
    size_t buckets;
    size_t used;
    size_t (*hash)(void *data);
    struct kv_pairs *table;
    enum tag *tags;
    int (*key_equal)(void *fkey, void *skey);
    int (*value_equal)(void *fvalue, void *svalue);
};
```

The one to choose would depend on the common memory access pattern, but both would increase the memory usage of the data structure. A third solution with no memory increase (that seems to be what you want) could be the following:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define FREE 0
#define DELETED 1

struct kv_pair {
    void *key;
    union {
        void *value;
        uintptr_t tag;
    } value;
};
```

You would check the tag only if key is NULL and if not, it's in use.